# button in jquery mobile doesnt work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I have a jquery mobile webpage. The page consists of a listView which is dynamically generated with jquery. In the end of this list i want to have a simple button , that when i hit it i simply alert something.

My **HTML** code looks like this :

```
<div data-role="page" id="Home">
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="albums">      
            </ul> 

            <form>
                <button id="loadMoreAlbums">More Albums...</button>
            </form>         
        </div>      
</div>
```

The button as you see is hard coded under the dynamically generated listView. The jquery for the button is as simple as that :

```
$("#loadMoreAlbums").click(function(){
            alert("yeah i am loaging more!");
});
```

I have 2 questions now:

**1)** When i load this page , the button is first loaded and i can see it for 2-3 seconds till the list is loaded and it goes in the end of the list. I dont really like that behavior , i would like that the button is "created" after the listView is already created, so that i dont see it like that in the page. However this is not a really problem , just for cosmetic reasons.

**2)** The real problem is that when i hit the button , instead of just alerting the simple text and nothing more , it "loads" the page again , and makes the listView vanish and only the button stay on screen. Why is it behaving like that though? Why is it trying to "load" the page again? I just want it to alert something , or do whatever my jquery tells it to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your HTML from

```
<button>...</button>
```

to

```
<button type="button">...</button>
```

By default, a `<button>` element has `type="submit"` and will submit the form when clicked.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#loadMoreAlbums").button().click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("yeah i am loaging more!");
});
```

The button is acting as a **submit**. By adding `e.preventDefault();` you can supress the submit action.